# Uncaught Error: Minified React error #423; Getting this error after successfully deploying next.js app on netlify

Tags: next.js, deployment, netlify

I don't know how to solve this error. I did not add netlify.toml file in my next app also. But everytime I am deploying it, I am getting this error. On netlify build logs there is no error showing.

[Adding screenshot of error image for more clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYQ93.png)

I tried by adding ErrorBoundary.jsx file in pages folder but this did not help me out.

```
import React from 'react';

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
  
      // Define a state variable to track whether is an error or not
      this.state = { hasError: false }
    }
    static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
      // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI
  
      return { hasError: true }
    }
    componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
      // You can use your own error logging service here
      console.log({ error, errorInfo })
    }
    render() {
      // Check if the error is thrown
      if (this.state.hasError) {
        // You can render any custom fallback UI
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>Oops, there is an error!</h2>
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => this.setState({ hasError: false })}
            >
              Try again?
            </button>
          </div>
        )
      }
  
      // Return children components in case of no error
  
      return this.props.children
    }
  }
  
  export default ErrorBoundary;
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue?